# Memory management on the array initialized for UITabBarController

Tags: iphone

I am still learning the ropes of Objective C and iPhone development. My weak point is memory management - any help will be much appreciated.

In the code below, where can I release the `NSMutableArray listOfViewControllers`? Keep in mind the function `createTab`s can be called within the app multiple times and the tabs are recreated dynamically based on user input. This function is within a ViewController.

1. If i do `[listofViewControllers release]` just before exiting the function, the app crashes when I have to call createTabs again
2. If I use a convenience method like below:

`NSMutableArray *listOfViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1]`

instead of:

```
NSMutableArray *listOfViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
```

it still crashes when createTabs is called again

```
-(void) createTabs
{

 //TODO - memory management - where do you release this?
 NSMutableArray *listOfViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 


 if ([briefingsArray count] > 0)
 {
  //add briefing(s) tab(s)
  for (Briefing *briefing in briefingsArray)
  {

   WebViewController *briefingViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithBriefing: briefing];


   [listOfViewControllers addObject:briefingViewController];

   [briefingViewController release];
  }



  [listOfViewControllers addObject:alertViewController];

  //add archives tab
  NSString *archiveURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: ARCHIVEURL, DeviceID()];

  UIViewController *archiveViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithURL:ARCHIVEURL andTitle:@"Archives" andImage:@"archive_icon.png"];
  [listOfViewControllers addObject:archiveViewController];

  [archiveViewController release];


 }


 NSArray *oldlistOfViewControllers = [self.tabBarController viewControllers];
 UIViewController *vcOld = [oldlistOfViewControllers objectAtIndex:[oldlistOfViewControllers count] -1];


 [listOfViewControllers addObject:vcOld];


 [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:listOfViewControllers
                                  animated:YES];


}
```

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that it has nothing to do with tab bar controller. When you did not release the array, the controllers in the array would never be dealloc and there was no problem at all. So it's likely that the problem might come from deallocation of your WebViewController.

Comment: tia - the question is - at what point can i release "listOfViewControllers" ?

Comment: At the end of the method, but that won't fix your crash right?

Comment: I'm quite positive that the problem comes from those controllers. You can try comment out some controller and see if it works. If it works only when you add no controller at all, try adding [UIViewController new] and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are creating here - listOfViewControllers - should be an instance variable of whatever object you are making here. Then you should alloc/init it inside the object's -init method, and release it in dealloc.

It is good practice (and usually necessary) to make an instance variable for anything you expect to exist after the end (or before the start) of a function call.

Comment: Alex,thanks for the response. I am not clear on waht you mean by "listofViewControllers - should be an instance variable of whatever object you are making here" - listOfViewControllers is of type NSMutableArray - and I dont need it to exist after the function call. I tried making it an instance variable and initializing it within the class's init method -which means, I have to empty it within createTabs before I start adding new tabs to it. That causes the app to crash too.

Comment: I believe the problem is that you actually do need listOfViewControllers to exist after the function call, because releasing it causes all the view controllers it contains to be released, and if they have no other owners they get dealloc'd. You'll have to experiment with it but if you narrowed it down to releasing that array it must be either the array itself or the contents of it causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After **[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:listOfViewControllers
                                  animated:YES];**, you can release your listOfViewControllers. Because tabBarController will retain this listOfViewControllers by copy policy.

You can see the UITabBarController reference about **viewControllers** property. This property adopts the copy policy.

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers
```

Comment: if i do it like you suggest, the next time createTabs is called, it crashes

Comment: While crashed, what did the log and memory stack say? Because self.tabBarController is the final owner of old listOfViewController, when it setViewControllers again, the view controllers inside listOfViewController will be released and then re-created again. Any accesses inside old listOfViewController will be invalid.